# Is it possible to create such a 3D diagram like the picture below?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, plot

This output/plot i want to create: [image]

How can i do this? Thank you in advance. Best Regards.
This is my 2D diagram code. I have 3 input colums (x-coordinate,y-coordinate,value)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,height=10cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar sampled,
    colorbar style={samples=13},
    grid=both,
    scale only axis=true,
    width=10cm,
    height=15cm,
    xtick={0,1,...,10},
    ytick={-8,-7,...,10},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=-8,
    ymax=8,
    ]

\addplot3[
    scatter,mark=text, text mark={\rule{6mm}{3mm}},only marks,
    point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
    ]
    table {
    x y color myvalue
2 3 1 100
4 3 2 3
2 7 3 0.75
7 7 4 45
8 5 2 3
2 5 1 10
4 -4 2 1
4 1 3 75
5 -1 4 4
5 2 2 3
1 -2 1 10
2 5 2 5
3 -8 3 75
4 5 4 42
7 -2 2 2
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @percusse i read the existing answer but i did not found a solution for my problem..... sorry

Comment: That's all there is that you can do about it. Especially the second to last answers show possibilities but as a question it is a duplicate.